# Calendar display options issue

Tags: info-visualisation, sliders, calendar

On the website of a client we have a calendar of events with quite a bit information in addition to the date and place. It looks like this:

[image]

- It's a jssor static slider
- The user can see/go to the next event:

  - By clicking and dragging from the slider
  - Clicking on the `View more →` button
- The slider shows the next event closest to today `1st` in the center and the rest consecutively
- At the bottom there is an indicator with dots showing the number of
  events, the filled dot is the event in the center
- In the left and right borders there are incomplete events to show there is more to see

---

All this is seen very clear for me, but not for the common user as they have let me know.

Issues:

- No one understands the use of the `View more →` button
- Nobody realizes that events can be moved by click and drag directly on the slider
- When the first event appears in the center after the last event, this is seen as an error
- The *cut* events on the left and right to show there is more hidden
  information, is perceived as a design error
- Removing the *cut* events from the ends makes no one know there are more events to see
- Nobody sees or understands the meaning of the dot indicator at the bottom

[image]

---

The only solution I see possible is putting the classic slider buttons to see if it's better understood (I have not tested it and breaks the overall page design)

[image]

---

Summing up: I think nobody realize the calendar of events is a slider.

I'm a little blind in terms of function, because I still seeing it very clear, some idea of an impartial eye can be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

This solution can be interesting, but also problematic.

The user should find the event that best suits his preference as soon as possible.In a monthly or several-month perspective, this solution is simply unbelievable. At the moment when, however, we are focused on the near future (a few days back or forth) - this is very good.

It would be annoying to look for event 27 when I have a 1-4 day slider visible (so search here should be neccessary)

---

**My observations about Your issues:**

1. Maybe changing "View more" to "Next data" will be clearer for user?
2. That's a problem, it's possibility to add a tutorial here (however, a lot of work. (with time users will adapt to the new control, at the moment this is not the pattern they know. However, adaptation can occur over time)
3. I don't get it. What type of error?
4. After click on the event i being redirect to page with specific event right?
5. Logically it's clear that there can be more events
6. Why not? This is quite a common design practice

**My advices:**

1. Depending on the significance of the events, the user aims to consider what will be most optimal for them.

What is the goal?

- Saving for an event?
- Watching the event?

---

2. Do research about calendar/time ui.:

[image]

3. Discuss the issue with client/programmers/users for more insights
   and optimal solution for objectives.